# уникальный id не задается, а пишет просто null

Tags: sql

подскажите, почему не создаются уникальные id номера автоматически, когда добавояю остальные значения, а пишет посто NULL

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Age int
);
```

Comment: `IDENTITY(1,1) not null` ?

Comment: попробовала, но в этом случае все равно ID надо вручную проставлять, он пишет что не может теперь оставить его NULL.....а я думала, что можно сделать так , что бы они автоматически по порядку ставились...или так нельзя?)) просто уникальные номера по порядку начиная с 1

Comment: значения добавляю так:
insert into Persons( LastName, FirstName, Age) values ('Ivanov', 'Ivan', '25)

Comment: Не воспроизводится: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=667b67e5800381ba8a631e2135cf85a6 Создайте fiddle, воспроизводящий проблему. PS. Может, IDENTITY_INSERT установлен в OFF?

Comment: Akina у вас работает!

Comment: я вот здесь делала и там никак не срабатывало https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

Comment: Если вы вставляете так, как указали в комментарии выше: `insert into Persons( LastName, FirstName, Age) values ('Ivanov', 'Ivan', '25)`, то у вас не происходит вставка из-за апострофа, стоящего перед `25`. Если вы его уберете, то вставка произойдет.
`INSERT INTO Persons (LastName, FirstName, Age) VALUES('Ivanov', 'Ivan', 25)`.  


UPD: перепроверил на сайте, что вы скинули. Там действительно ставится _null_ - неизвестно почему. Проверил [тут] (https://sqliteonline.com) - всё нормально, вставляется нужное значение.

Comment: На сайте w3schools используется встроенный в браузер движок WebSQL.